# cannot view mp4 when running site from apache2.4 server

Tags: apache2.4

tested my website locally and everything works. But when I ported it to my apache2 server the mp4 file does not play/show. It is there on the website since there is an onclick function that works where the video should be.I just cannot see it.

I added "AddType video/mp4 .mp4" to my apache.conf file (running apache2.4.18 ububtu 16.04) and reloaded but still cannot view it.

I have multiple virtial sites on the server and would like to make the change so all sites can play mp4 properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: I removed AddType from apache.conf. Tried creating a .htaccess file with the single line "AddType video/mp4 .mp4" in both the root directory for one of the sites and then in the directory where the media is being served. Neither worked

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/scojopa/d50Luyp0/1/

Comment: Although using AddType should work, I would suggest adding it to your mime.types file first and re-trying.